# MPAndroidChart - In CombinedChart show Line Data and Bar Data on separate Buttons click respectively

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

In [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library I have combined chart which consist of 1 Line data and 1 Bar data. I have 2 buttons lets say on

- Button 1 click Bar Data should be shown and Line Data should Hide.
- Button 2 click Line Data should be shown and Bar Data should Hide.

Initially I have loaded the Bar Chart same I have done on Button 1 Click event. What I am doing at the moment is

- on Button 1 Click I do fllowing :

  `CombinedData data = new CombinedData(getXAxisValues());
   data.setData(generateBarData());
   mChart.setData(data);
   mChart.invalidate();`
- on Button 2 Click:

  `mChart.getData().removeDataSet(mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0));
   mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
   mChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
   CombinedData data = new CombinedData(getXAxisValues());
   data.setData(generateLineData());
   mChart.setData(data);
   mChart.invalidate();`

On Button 2 click it gives me following exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData.notifyDataChanged()' on a
>   null object reference

I am new with Android programming. Kindly help me in this matter. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In on button 2 click you are removing the data from the chart and then trying to retrieve it to call notifyDataSetChanged. The chart is returning null because there is no data.

I would remove this line  `mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();` it does nothing.
And move `mChart.notifyDataSetChanged()` to below `mChart.setData(data);`

Comment: Got rid of the error i was facing.
I have changed my code with following Lines.
 CombinedData data = mChart.getData();
data.removeDataSet(mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0));
data.setData(generateLineData());
mChart.setData(data);
mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

Now on Button 2 Click Bar data does not removed and Line Data is shown along with it.